# Is it possible to place a map marker with a highscore on a Google map in Android by pressing a button?

Tags: android, android-maps

I have created a game where the user can upload their high score and name to my database, the scores can also be downloaded and viewed. I am now thinking about creating a map that shows all the names and scores of all the players on map markers. I have created a view map button for now, and got the API key set up, the map is working.

Before I continue with this I wanted to know if this was even possible in Android? Can you pass info such as a nickname, score and map marker to a map and somehow store on a server it so that all locations etc can be seen by all players?

Basically a map that displays high-scores.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only advice would be to store each persons lat/lon and score in an xml file on the server. When you want to view the map you download the xml file and parse it placing each lat/lon on the map with their score.

You can find information about Map Overlays here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/drawing-an-image-as-a-map-overlay2

Also you could create a javascript/php/perl/etc scrip that would take in a users lat/lon/score and add it to the XML file.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have done this before a while ago, well sort of. I used an XML file to show markers on a Google map and JavaScript to put them on, I forgot how I did it, but how could this be done within an android application, would I have to show a web page via the Android phone?

Thanks

Comment: There is an Android MapView class that you would display. Then use the MapOverlay class to add the balloons on them at certain lat/lon. Here is the google tutorial for MapView's http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that's possible. As a matter of fact, you can put almost anything you like into a map marker. I recommend you take a look at the [mapview-balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) project for some implementation examples.

Regarding the storage: you would have to centralize that on some server and have devices fetch a list of all information (including geographical position) from there to display on the map. New scores should be uploaded to the server, obviously.